# Implementation of multiplier system of processor using sequence system - is it possible?

Tags: microprocessor, computer-architecture

I am in the course of learning about the processor, sequential systems, etc. I came across this question:

Is multiplier processor may be implemented as a sequence system?

I can not answer that. Can someone explain this?

Comment: I don't even understand what are you asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "sequential system" is a system that produces the desired result by performing a sequence of tasks. So, for a processor, the task of multiplication can be performed by a sequence of additions.

If you want to calculate `7 x 5`, you could start with `0`, then add `7` to that number `5` times. The result will be `35`, which is the correct answer.

While this *is* possible, it is *not* how multiplication is done inside today's processors.